# Pass data from node js to android to make a phone call?

Tags: android, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working with Alexa skills and stuck in some problem where I have to make a phone call by passing data(phone number) from nodejs to android (Same like intent.Action_call). As I have searched about it but didn't get any proper answer so if you could help me in this then it will make my day...

Comment: Looks like, you have to fetch phone numbers from Node JS backend server. And then  you have to make a call using Intent.Action_call. correct me, If my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @varatharajan yeah, I have to make a call like intent.Action_call but without any external android app, only like implicit intent that invokes system component in android.

Comment: You want to make a call without installing an App that supports that?

Comment: @Henry I hope that you have used google assistance in which if you say call xyz then it makes a phone call for you so like this I have to do in node js app where i  will pass my data (phone number) to the android device that invoke phone call intent.

Comment: And you think this isn't done by an App?

Comment: @Henry I know that this can be done by an android app but can't say about node  js.